# How to calculate difference between rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking to create a query that takes a customer record and compares it to the prior months version to determine if they had an increase or decrease in their costs. Here's an example of the data I'm hoping to generate:

| customer_id | event_date | amount | change_from_prior_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 30 | N/A |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 | 45 | Increase |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 | 25 | Decrease |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 | 25 | N/A |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 | 10 | Decrease |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 30 | Increase |

I can query for the first three columns, but I have no idea how to do the `change_from_prior_month` one. It seems that perhaps `Lag` might be a good approach, but I can't tell how you'd ensure that it is comparing against a criteria (i.e. customer_id) instead of just the record prior, which could be a different customer.

Here's an example of my current query:

```
SELECT format_date('%Y-%m',event_date) as event_date, customer_id, sum(cost) as cost
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY event_date, customer_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take advantage of window functions, here you have a working example that will show you the expected field (decrease/increase/n.a) and the detailed data (current amount, previous month amount)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag

```
WITH raw_data AS (
SELECT 1 AS customer_id, CAST("2022-08-01" AS date) AS  event_date, 30 AS amount
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,CAST("2022-09-01"AS date),45
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, CAST("2022-10-01"AS date), 25
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CAST("2022-09-01"AS date),  25
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CAST("2022-10-01"AS date),  10 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CAST("2022-11-01"AS date),  30)

SELECT customer_id,
  event_date,
  amount,
  LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY event_date ASC) AS preceding_amount,
  CASE WHEN LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY event_date ASC) IS NULL THEN "N/A"
    WHEN (amount-LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY event_date ASC)) > 0 THEN "INCREASE"
    ELSE "DECREASE" END as difference_prev_month
FROM raw_data
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, you can use `LAG`. To ensure the right comparison, use `PARTITION BY`. Details in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag).

Example:

```sql
WITH your_table AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS customer_id, '2022-08-01' AS event_date, 30 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2022-09-01',   45 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, '2022-10-01',   25 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, '2022-09-01', 25 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, '2022-10-01', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2022-11-01', 30
)

SELECT 
*,
amount - LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY event_date) AS change_from_prior_month
FROM your_table
ORDER BY customer_id, event_date
```